# select id строки с предпоследней датой записи

Tags: sql-server

Есть запрос

```
SELECT  material_id,
        mat_trans_line_id,
        unit_det_id, 
        mat_trans_line_date 
INTO #table1
FROM    tbl_mat_trans
```

который выдает

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
material_id | mat_trans_line_id | unit_det_id | mat_trans_line_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      33    |          6399     |        42   | 2016-01-15 12:22:28.000
      33    |          7125     |        41   | 2016-04-30 11:24:30.000
      33    |          9796     |        42   | 2016-01-01 11:02:00.000
      33    |          11355    |        42   | 2016-09-28 09:59:31.000
      34    |          11356    |        42   | 2016-09-28 09:59:31.000
      34    |          9797     |        42   | 2016-01-01 11:02:00.000
      34    |          7126     |        41   | 2016-04-30 11:24:30.000
      34    |          6400     |        42   | 2016-01-15 12:22:28.000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Нужно чтобы следующим запросом Можно было взять группированную таблицу по mat_trans_line_id у которого mat_trans_line_date является предпоследней датой. То есть сортировка по дате и взять предпоследнюю. Что то вроде этого:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
material_id | mat_trans_line_id | unit_det_id | mat_trans_line_date
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      33    |          7125     |        41   | 2016-04-30 11:24:30.000
      34    |          7126     |        41   | 2016-04-30 11:24:30.000
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select *
  from (
    select A.*,
           row_number() over(partition by material_id order by mat_trans_line_date desc) rn
      from #table1
  ) A
  where rn=2
```

В принципе вы можете применить нумерацию строк в заданной сортировке еще на этапе чтения первой таблицы

Comment: Отлично!!! Самый раз. Благодарю за помощь!