# Объединенный отчет из двух таблиц SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно вывести item_id и price_in_rub. Price_in_rub – стоимость rub, считается как price из таблицы items умноженная на курс валюты на максимальную дату выставления курса из таблицы rates.

Выглядит все это примерно так:
Например: item_id=5 price = 20 EUR, в таблице rates максимальная дата выставления курса евро – 13 января, на эту дату курс равнялся 3,0. Итого price_in_rub 20*3,0 = 60.

```
items   
item_id |price  | currency  
1       |100    | USD   
2       |10     | EUR   
3       |20     | USD   
4       |40     | USD   
5       |20     | EUR   
7       |400    | USD

rates
currency|   date    |   rate
USD     | 10.01.2017|   1,0
USD     | 11.01.2017|   1,5
USD     | 12.01.2017|   2,0
EUR     | 13.01.2917|   3,0
EUR     | 12.01.2017|   2,5
```

Comment: Получите в подзапросе курс, актуальный на требуемую дату (или даты актуальных записей курсов - это проще), и свяжите с ним таблицу итемов (во втором случае - и курсов).

Comment: Да, подзапросом вроде этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572040/194569 (только RN=1) берете последние курсы и джоинете это к items

Comment: "максимальная дата выставления курса евро – 12 января" по вашим данным максимальная дата курса - 13 января:   EUR     | 13.01.2917|   3,0 || EUR     | 12.01.2017|   2,5

Comment: @Serge-Nazarenko, исправил

Comment: @PavelBobrov подошло?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko, это определенно поможет кому-то, кто столкнется с аналогичной проблемой. Но , к сожалению, не мой случай. Мне необходимо провернуть все это в одном запросе и без создания новых объектов

Comment: @PavelBobrov Вам предоставили решение в одном запросе и без создания новых объектов, вас смущает словосочетание "корелированый подзапрос" ? Вы пробовали запускать предоставленный код?

Comment: @SergeNazarenko, да, пробовал запускать в phpmuadmin. Но просидев над ним 3 часа так и не смог заставить работать

Comment: @PavelBobrov а у вас точно sql-server, а не mysql?

Comment: Что бы не забрасали помидорами на всякий случай уточню. С sql я был знаком ранее, но пользовался всего парой операторов в рамках cs50 и этого было достаточно. Но вдруг требования возросли и жизнь сильно осложнилась. За последние 3 дня я просидел над ним порядка 20 часов, даже сервер домашний развернул

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68445/discussion-between-serge-nazarenko-and-pavel-bobrov).

Answer (score 3):

Решение с корелированым подзапросом:

```
SELECT
    itm.item_id
    ,(itm.price * cur.rate) price_in_rub
FROM items itm
    CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 rate
            FROM rates
            WHERE itm.currency = rates.currency
            ORDER BY date desc
        ) cur
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой вариант по быстрее будет:

```
SELECT it.item_id, it.price*r.rate AS price_in_rub
FROM dbo.items AS it 
JOIN dbo.rates AS r ON it.currency = r.currency
WHERE r.date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM dbo.rates AS r2 WHERE r.currency = r2.currency)
```

Comment: А какую роль тут играет dbo?

Comment: @PavelBobrov это наименование схемы по умолчанию - можете убрать из текста запроса или подставить свою схему, где хранятся ваши таблицы