# Выборка данных самой последней даты

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть две таблицы `room`, `journal`

```
room
-----------------
id int,
name varchar(20)


journal
-----------------
id int,
date timestamp,
degree char(3),
room_id int
```

Как выбрать данные как `room.name`, `journal.date`, `journal.degree` из таблиц, при условии что данные должны быть самого последнего дня `max(journal.date)`, для каждого `room.name`

Comment: СУБД у вас какая?

Comment: БД `postgresql`

Comment: А версия какая?

Comment: Версия 9.3 под windows

Comment: посчитайте строки в группе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572040/194569 и возьмите первую, при сортировке по убыванию даты (разумеется сделав обычный join двух таблиц)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В версии PostgreSQL 9.3 можно воспользоваться оконными функциями:

```
select distinct
    room.name
    ,first_value(journal.date) OVER (partition by room.id order by journal.date desc, journal.id desc)
    ,first_value(journal.degree) OVER (partition by room.id order by journal.date desc, journal.id desc)
from room 
    inner join journal ON room.id = journal.room_id
```

Comment: Тогда записей будет столько сколько в обычном join таблиц. т.е. будут записи за все даты, только в них будут одинаковые данные с первой записи. лучше все таки пронумеровать и взять первые

Comment: Нет не получилось выводит все данные :(

Comment: забыл distinct добавить

Comment: @Xfirab скиньте вывод, запрос с distinct должен работать

Comment: Не верно выводит данные, т.е. не максимальные даты. Мне нужно  примерно `select max(date), room_id from journal group by room_id`

Comment: OVER (partition by room.id order by journal.date desc, journal.id desc) нужен descпосле каждого столбца сортировки, проверьте

Comment: @Xfirab Ответ в текущем виде просто обязан работать верно, так же как и тот, что я дал вам комментом к вашему вопросу (надеюсь вы его уже опробовали). если что то не так, то адаптируйте под свою структуру и данные.

Comment: @Xfirab Может вы в выборке написали не только name и эти 2 колонки, а например еще какие нибудь id, тогда distinct конечно не поможет ...

Comment: Спасибо всем, все работает