# Исключение дубликатов из запросов по одному полю

Tags: oracle, group-by

Здравствуйте, такая проблема, нужно исключить данные с одинаковыми idclient, чтобы возвращал любую строку не важно какую главное одну.
DISTINCT как я понял не поможет, попробывал GROUP BY, но выдает ошибку:
-1;ORA-00979: выражение не является выражением GROUP BY
Сам запрос:

```
SELECT 
                         idclient,
                         id,
                         name,
                         iditemtype,
                         price
          FROM items
          WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%' || LOWER(xdb_access.cnv(in_find) || '%')
            AND isVisible = 1
            AND xdb_access.equalsDateMinute(sysdate, isonline) <= t_time_online
            AND idclient != in_idclient
          GROUP BY idclient
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572040/194569  или воспользуйтесь групповыми функциями по всем колонкам кроме idclient. Если уж нет разницы какие именно данные возвращаются может быть проще взять например максимумы (хотя значения колонок могут оказаться из разных записей, но возможно это вам будет не критично)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите использовать аналитику, то уберите group by:

```
select * from
(
SELECT 
                     idclient,
                     id,
                     name,
                     iditemtype,
                     price,
row_number() over (partition by idclient order by idclient, id, name, 
iditemtype, price) rn
      FROM items
      WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%' || LOWER(xdb_access.cnv(in_find) || '%')
        AND isVisible = 1
        AND xdb_access.equalsDateMinute(sysdate, isonline) <= t_time_online
        AND idclient != in_idclient

)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Немного поторопился с правильностью выбора, дел в том, что если есть только один idclient, то запрос ничего не возвращает. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Хотя нет, всё работает правильно, я разобрался в чем причина, но никак не пойму, почему она вообще возникла

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте пронумеровать строки аналитикой и выбрать первую (или любую другую)

```
select * from
(
SELECT 
                         idclient,
                         id,
                         name,
                         iditemtype,
                         price,
row_number() over (partition by idclient order by idclient) rn
          FROM items
          WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE '%' || LOWER(xdb_access.cnv(in_find) || '%')
            AND isVisible = 1
            AND xdb_access.equalsDateMinute(sysdate, isonline) <= t_time_online
            AND idclient != in_idclient
          GROUP BY idclient
)
where rn = 1
```

Comment: К сожалению, работать не будет. Таже ошибка, что и в вопросе.