# Как получить последние уникальные записи по 2 столбцам?

Tags: postgresql

Вот есть такая таблица:

```
id      page data time 
30005    1    а    13304214124
30005    2    а    13304214124
30006    3         13304214124
30005    1    b    14304214124
30005    2    b    14304214124
```

Мы знаем id и массив page. 
Нужно для каждого id и page достать data, но только уникальные последние по столбцу time.

То есть зная что id=30005 и page=1 и 2.
Нужно получить эти записи где data равна b

Comment: Что то в этом роде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572040/194569 только брать конечно первую с конца запись

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если просто - использовать расширенную возможность синтаксиса `distinct on`

```
select distinct on (id, page) id, page, data, time
from tablename
where id = ? and page in (...)
order by id, page, time desc
```

Есть проблемы с производительностью, `distinct` не умеет самостоятельно делать `loose index scan` и будет просматривать много лишних данных, особенно если у вас много разных time

Вариант поинтереснее по производительности - сделать `loose index scan` [вручную через рекурсивный `CTE`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) и специально для этого подходящий индекс.

Если как в примере у вас немного исходных данных, то для всех актуальных версий баз (строго говоря начиная с 9.3) можно сделать `loose index scan` чуть проще:

```
select id, page, date, time
from (values(1),(2)) as r(need_page)
join lateral (
    select id, page, date, time
    from tablename
    where id = ? and page = need_page
    order by time desc
    limit 1
) subquery on true
```

Этот запрос по индексу `btree(id, page, time)` (или `btree(page, id, time)`, если рациональнее для других ваших запросов) будет идти весьма хорошо.