# SQL. Как из MAX(val) получить еще и id

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть ли способ в MAX получить вместе с id также name?

```
SELECT name FROM
(SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM T GROUP BY City) AS Sel
INNER JOIN T ON T.id = Sel.id;
```

Это решение по скорости хорошо работает?

```
SELECT t1.name FROM T AS T1
LEFT JOIN T AS T2 ON T1.id < T2.id
WHERE T2.id IS NULL AND T1.City = T2.City;
```

Comment: `select name from T order by id desc limit 1`

Comment: Но, если нужно не для всей таблицы, а по группам?

Comment: тогда что нибудь такое https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496532/194569

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/842378/203622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM T 
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM T GROUP BY City)
```