# Отсечение лишних кортежей

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Всем привет, есть вот такая выборка из БД

```
v_id| product_id | price
1   | 1          | 234
2   | 1          | 333
3   | 1          | 222
4   | 2          | 123
5   | 5          | 22
6   | 2          | 5
```

Итак, **суть вопроса:**
Как выбрать только 1 кортеж v_id/product_id, для каждого product_id

Comment: Для postgresql релевантный ответ есть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/842378/203622 distinct on скорей всего окажется лучше подзапроса с группировкой.

Comment: Определитесь с RDBMS. Если MySQL - укажите точную версию. *выбрать только 1 кортеж* Какой именно? Сформулируйте признак. "Любой" - как бы не подойдёт...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE v_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(tableName.v_id)
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY product_id,price)
ORDER BY 2
```

Ответ был взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282393/sql-select-only-one-row-of-table-with-same-value)