# Столбец "user_purchases.product" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица `user_purchases` в которой содержится:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| user_login |    date    |   product  |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 31.03.2999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 31.03.1999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 01.04.2999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 01.04.1999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Мне нужно вытащить **последнюю дату покупки по каждому пользователю**,
для этого я агрегирую таблицу по пользователям, затем ищу максимальную дату

```
SELECT
  user_purchases.user_login AS user_login,
  max(user_purchases.date) AS date
FROM user_purchases
GROUP BY user_purchases.user_login;

+------------+------------+
| user_login |    date    |
+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 01.04.2999 |
+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 01.04.1999 |
+------------+------------+
```

А как получить **последний купленный товар по каждому пользователю**?
например что бы это выглядело так:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| user_login |    date    |   product  |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 01.04.2999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 01.04.1999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

Например если пишу такой запрос то получаю ошибку:

```
SELECT
  user_purchases.user_login AS user_login,
  max(user_purchases.date) AS date,
  user_purchases.product AS product
FROM user_purchases
GROUP BY user_purchases.user_login;
```

Comment: Как соотносится заголовок с содержимым вопроса? Какая СУБД?

Comment: Укажите СУБД , которые вы используете. Для чего Вам тут GROUP BY вообще не понятно. В поле product всегда лежит последний купленный товар?

Comment: в данный момент используется  microsoft sqlserver в дальнейшем скорее всего перейдем на oracle. В поле product лежит купленный товар в конкретную дату.

Comment: Если я не буду делать GROUP BY по пользователям,  получу просто последнюю покупку.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572040/194569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующий запрос:

```
SELECT
  user_login, date, product  
FROM user_purchases up1
WHERE date = (SELECT max(up2.date)
              FROM user_purchases up2
              WHERE up1.user_login = up2.user_login)
```

Comment: Да работает, но очень, очень долго.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас отсутствуют индексы на столбцах по которым работают условия