# Выборка уникальных по полю значений Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, plpgsql

Имеется таблица значений public.user_ips:

```
user_ID | token| device_id |    IP        | user_agent         |    last_seen  |
user1     |token1_1| device_id1_1|192.168.1.1| client_name1 |  timestamp1   |
user1    |token1_2| device_id1_1|192.168.1.2| client_name1 |  timestamp1_2   |
user1    |token1_3| device_id1_2|192.168.1.3| client_name1 |  timestamp1_3   |
user2    |token2_1 | device_id2_1|192.168.1.4| client_name2 |  timestamp2_1   |
```

.....

Делаю выборку нужных значений запросом, преобразовывая timestamp в нужное представление:

```
SELECT device_id, ip,user_agent, to_timestamp(cast (substring(cast(last_seen as text), 1 , 10) as int))  AT TIME ZONE 'UTC -3' as time
FROM public.user_ips 
WHERE  user_id = 'user1' 
order BY device_id asc;
```

В результате данного запроса получаю следующий вывод:

```
user_ID | device_id |    IP        |    user_agent         |    time  |
user1    | device_id1_1|192.168.1.1| client_name1 |  timestamp1   |
user1    | device_id1_1|192.168.1.2| client_name1 |  timestamp1_2   |
user1    | device_id1_2|192.168.1.3| client_name1 |  timestamp1_3   |
```

Проблема в следующем - необходимо изменить запрос так, чтобы в выводе не было строк с одинаковым `device_id1_1`, а оставался только с более свежим timestamp.
Пробовал использовать `distinct ON (device_id)`, но в выводе остается только первая найденная строка с более "старым" timestamp.
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572033/194569 только там запись брали предпоследнюю, поэтому RN=2 был

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас посмотрю!

Comment: Не понятно, что значит A.*?

Comment: Группировка по `user_id, device_id` и `FIRST_RECORD(fieldname) OVER (PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY last_seen DESC)` по остальным полям

Comment: *что значит A.*?* Алиас это, алиас...

Comment: @cavabanga Это алиас и там опечатка, потому что A встречается только снаружи. имелось ввиду `from #table1 A` или заменить `A.*` на `#table1.*`

Comment: @Mike,@Akina Спасибо за помощь и пояснения - все получилось.