# Запрос строк по их номерам из Postgre из скрипта Python

Tags: python, postgresql

Я новичок в работе с базами данных и прошу совета.
Задача. Есть таблица в Postgre и нужно взять из нее строки по их номерам из скрипта Python. Мне удалось добиться нужного результата в самом редакторе pgAdmin, но не получается интегрировать его в скрипт Python. Код прикладываю ниже. В результате выполнения print отдает None. Прошу совета как получить строки с 550-600 из скрипта Python?

````
    (
        SELECT
            name,
            url,
            price,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY name)
        FROM
            ozon
    ) x
WHERE
    ROW_NUMBER BETWEEN 580 AND 590;""")
    print(cursor.execute(select))```
````

Comment: Добавить в начале запроса `select * from`. В подзапросе дать имя (алиас) для номера строки `ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY name) as RN`. Использовать это имя в `where RN between ...` Как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/572033/select-id-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8/572040#572040

Comment: Mike, благодарю тебя от всего сердца ты супер храни тебя господь чтоб у тебя все хорошо в жизни было обнял руку пожал реально спас невероятно