# Получение данных из postgres с условиями 2.0

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, оптимизация-запросов

Есть две таблицы: `users` и `user_status`.

1. Код создания таблицы `users`.

```
CREATE TABLE users(      
    Id SERIAL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    user_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

2. Код создания таблицы `user_status`.

```
CREATE TABLE user_status(
    Id SERIAL,
    user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    status TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_in date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    time_in time without time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME(0)
);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно получить последнее вхождение каждого user'a ЗА ТЕКУЩУЮ дату.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
user_name  ---  status

Виктор        Статус 1
Павел         Статус 2
Екатерина     Статус 3
Светлана      Статус 2
Федор         Статус 1
Роман         Статус 2
```

Так же, если возможно, подскажите общие недочеты таблицы.
Например, не назначены PK и FK. Поле таблицы `users` - `user_id` - уникально, и соответствует аналогичному полю в таблице `user_status`, но если их назначать на PK и FK, идет ошибка ввода, то есть, если один из пользователей выбирает статус, его данные не помещаются второй раз в таблицу users, так как он по сути уже там есть.

Но важнее запрос с последними вхождениями.

Всем большое спасибо! Все женщин с праздником!

Comment: Дайте пример данных не картинкой, а как INSERT INTO.

Comment: На счет "ошибок ввода" не ясно. в таблице users id должен быть PK, а в таблице user_status user_id должен быть FK ссылающийся на таблицу users. А основной недочет в том, что в таблице user_status поля даты и времени это два отдельных поля. Даты лучше хранить в виде дат (т.е. timestamp (with time zone ?)), тогда можно будет писать запросы вида `where date >= current_date` что бы получить все записи за сегодня. А сейчас надо еще текущую дату преобразовывать в какой то странный формат в котором у вас даты лежат.

Comment: А что до последних строк, то `row_number() over(partition by user_id order by time_in desc) as RN` дает нумерацию строк, оборачиваем внешним запросом и where RN=1 дает нам только последние. В общем как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/572040/194569

Comment: INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_id) VALUES (some_name, some_id)

Comment: INSERT INTO user_status(user_id, status) VALUES (some_id, some_status)

Comment: Mike, немного не понял, какой лучше формат для дат взять? То есть, надо даты и время в один столбец?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятен смысл таблиц у вас. Например - users. Обычно смысл такой таблицы - это список всех уникальных пользователей, поэтому непонятно, когда вы пишите про "последнее вхождение в таблицу users".

В таблице users привычнее видеть что каждый пользователь уникален, т.е. входит один раз, для их различия введен первичный ключ (PK) - id, и, как и в жизни, у них могут быть одинаковые имена. У вас же есть записи с одним и тем же user_id и name в таблице users повторяются. В чем смысл этой таблицы у вас?

Если отбросить этот момент, то, предположительно, таблица user_status содержит какие-то статусы для разных пользователей (связь по полю user_id).Исходя из того, что поле id у вас SERIAL, т.е. целое, автоинкрементируемое (т.е. не вставляется "руками" и каждый раз само увеличивается и в общем-то должно быть первичным ключом), то... Как бы напрашивается, что последнее вхождение" для любого пользователя (user_id) за текущую дату будет

```
select max(id), user_id 
from user_status where date_in = CURRENT_DATE 
group by user_id, date_in;
```

Пока запомним, что нам нужен именно максимальный ID каждого пользователя (user_id) из таблицы user_status на нужную дату (текущую, по условию задачи).

Чтобы вывести статусы для конкретных пользователей нам нужно объединить эти таблицы через JOIN, в общем виде это было бы так:

```
select user_status.user_id, user_name, status 
from user_status 
join users on users.user_id = user_status.user_id 
order by user_status.id;
```

Но нам нужны только последние статусы по каждому пользователю за текущую дату, так что добавим еще условие - максимальный id из user_status для каждого пользователя за текущую дату:

```
select user_status.user_id, user_name, status 
from user_status 
join users on users.user_id = user_status.user_id 
    where user_status.id IN (
        select max(id) 
        from user_status 
            where date_in=CURRENT_DATE 
        group by user_id
    )
 group by user_status.user_id, users.user_name, status order by user_status.user_id;
```

P.S. Я все же не понимаю вашу таблицу users, зачем несколько раз в нее записывать пользователей? Я бы сделал первичный ключ по user_id и если такой пользователь уже есть не заносил бы его повторно.

Ну и в таблице user_status явно напрашивается: первичный ключ по полю id, возможно составной индекс по user_id и date_in, но.... Мне кажется вам стоит все же почитать теорию и разобраться, какие задачи вы решаете и какие таблицы и почему создаете?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Дмитрий! Спасибо за развернутый ответ! То есть, у меня ошибка изначально из-за неправильного проектирования бд. Согласен, опыта мало, я только учусь. Переделаю все.  Скажите, с вами можно связаться в телеграм? Есть кое какой интересный момент. Если это уместно, конечно же.

Comment: Насчет телеграм, спасибо, но нет. У меня посещение Stackoverflow регламентированное )

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Итак, вы рекомендуете исправить таблицу, более правильно подойти к их предназначению и функциям. Хорошо, займусь этим.

Comment: Кстати, второй и третий (объединенный) запросы вернули пустой ответ. Без ошибки, но пустой.

Comment: Да, Дмитрий, возможно я упустил важную вещь, для правильного понимания задачи. id, который в обоих таблицах ничего не значит, просто счетчик полей. Дело в том, что таблицы заполняются автоматически, телеграм-ботом. Смысл которого зафиксировать статус каждого пользователя, а потом вернуть его, по требованию. Когда пользователь фиксирует свой статус, бот отправляет его данные двумя запросами в соответствующие поля двух таблиц.

Comment: Я поправил второй и третий запросы под ВАШИ таблицы, они были чуть не точно написаны. Кстати, мы же про Постгрес или не только? В заголовке вопроса Postgres, а метки стоят еще и для MySQL. Но зачем в таблице users несколько раз записывать одних и тех же пользователей я так и не смог понять )

Comment: Здравствуйте, Дмитрий! Большое спасибо за помощь. Повторения в users... моя криворукость))) Но ваш запрос работает исправно, и ни разу не подвел.

Comment: Дмитрий, если не сложно, посмотрите мой новый вопрос. Ваше мнение мне бы очень пригодилось. Заранее спасибо!